# Is there a way to stop a repetitive function executing on a page by an other way than change my code and reloading the page?

Tags: javascript

I'm just a beginner in programmation and I'm not speaking a very correct english, but I'll try to be clear:
When I have a repetitive function (eg:: setInterval(function, 1000)) which I'm executing on a page, I would like to be able to stop it directly on the page, and not by changing my code and reloading the page at each time, which I think make me lose time. (it's stressing to have the function executing without stop). Do you know if it's possible, or if there is no other way that change the code and reload the page ?
Thank you :)
Anacarde

Comment: I found a plugin for firefox who permit me to disable javaScript (name is : "disable javaScript").

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)?

```
intervalID = setInterval(()=>{}, 1000);
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

To stop it directly on the page - `addEventListener` with handler that call `clearInterval`.

Comment: No, actually, I'm not looking for a line code, I wanted to know if there is a way to stop directly making loading a page from a navigator. For ex: if i execute a function: setInterval(fun(){console.log("hello")},1000) on my navigator, I will have my console making "hello" each second, then, to stop it, I will no have other choice that changing my code and reloading my page, because if I just reload it, I'll still have my console making "hello" each seconds. 3 - Therefore, I would like to know (and if you know) if there is a simplier way to stop loading a page. (but maybe there isn't :s?).

Comment: if you want to update code without reloading page - take a look to [HMR](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/).  

If you want page to stop loading and be able to debug - [debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)

Reload the page after source code was changed - [webpack watcher](https://survivejs.com/webpack/developing/webpack-dev-server/)